# Open new windows in UWP app with MvvmCross

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, mvvmcross, viewmodel

I try to open a page in a **new window** in my UWP app. Is this possible with the `IMvxNavigationService` provided by MvvmCross? Right now it only replaces the page in the current window.

**Navigation flow**
[image: Navigatin flow]

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel: MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public MyViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public MvxCommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    public override void Prepare()
    {
        base.Prepare();
        MyCommand = new MvxCommand<>(MyEvent);
    }

    private void MyEvent()
    {
        _navigationService.Navigate<OtherViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now realized that I could implement a custom presenter and use the new [AppWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/app-window).

**MvxWindowPresentationAttribute.cs**

```
public class MvxWindowPresentationAttribute : MvxBasePresentationAttribute
{
}
```

**CustomMvxWindowsViewPresenter.cs**

```
public class CustomMvxWindowsViewPresenter : MvxWindowsViewPresenter
{
    public CustomMvxWindowsViewPresenter(IMvxWindowsFrame rootFrame) : base(rootFrame)
    {
    }

    public override void RegisterAttributeTypes()
    {
        base.RegisterAttributeTypes();
        AttributeTypesToActionsDictionary.Register<MvxWindowPresentationAttribute>(ShowWindow, CloseWindow);
    }

    private Task<bool> CloseWindow(IMvxViewModel viewModel, MvxWindowPresentationAttribute attribute)
    {
        return base.ClosePage(viewModel, attribute);
    }

    private Task<bool> ShowWindow(Type viewType, MvxWindowPresentationAttribute attribute,
        MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var requestText = GetRequestText(request);
                var viewsContainer = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();

                await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
                    async () => {
                        var appWindow = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync();
                        var appWindowContentFrame = new Frame();
                        appWindowContentFrame.Navigate(viewType, requestText);
                        ElementCompositionPreview.SetAppWindowContent(appWindow, appWindowContentFrame);
                        await appWindow.TryShowAsync();
                        HandleBackButtonVisibility();
                    });
                return true;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**Setup.cs**

```
protected override IMvxWindowsViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter(IMvxWindowsFrame rootFrame)
{
    return new CustomMvxWindowsViewPresenter(rootFrame);
}
```

The only thing left to do is to annotate your views with the created attribute `MvxWindowPresentation`.

**OtherView.xaml.cs**

```
[MvxWindowPresentation]
public sealed partial class OtherView : MvxWindowsPage 
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to open a new window in UWP, the more traditional way is recommended

```cs
public static async Task<bool> TryOpenNewWindow(Type page)
{
    CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    int newViewId = 0;
    await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(page);
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
        Window.Current.Activate();

        newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    });
    bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
    return viewShown;
}
```

**Usage**

```cs
bool isShow = await TryOpenNewWindow(typeof(MyPage));
```

When using MVVMCross, the reason for navigating only in the current window and not in the new window may be that you have not registered the Frame of the new window.

If you follow the [documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/uwp/universal-windows-platform-uwp), you may need to re-register `public class Setup: MvxWindowsSetup` when creating a new window.

Best regards.